# Best to use global or custom named GCD queues?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

My understanding is that `// 001` gets a high priority concurrent queue

```
// 001
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
```

and that `// 002` creates a new custom serial queue

```
// 002
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("bgQueue", NULL);
```

My question, is there a chance that other processes (on the iPhone, other apps etc.) will be queued on the global queues so you may have to wait (albeit briefly) to execute. If this is the case would it be best to always create custom queues where you know you have sole access?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- The `001` *gets* the high-priority queue, not *creates* it. The three global queues are automatically created for your application; they are always available.
- The three global queues are global only within your application, in the same sense as global variables are global. These queues are still private to each application in which they are created.
- The main difference between private and global queue <strike>is</strike> used to be that private queues <strike>are</strike> were *sequential*, while global queues are *concurrent*. The differences between the two are summarized in [Table 3-1 of GCD documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html). **EDIT :** In OS X v10.7 and later, the private queues can now also be concurrent by passing `DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT` (thanks, Rob, for the correction).

Comment: Private queues can now also be concurrent by passing `DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT`.

Comment: @RobNapier That's very nice to know! Thank you very much for the correction, I edited the answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Private concurrent queues are useful with dispatch_barrier_[a]sync, and also are suspendable without impacting other unrelated work that would be on the global queue.